# Key Bindings with JOGL GLCanvas (java)

Tags: java, jogl, key-bindings, glcanvas

Just curious, how would you use key bindings with the openGL GLCanvas? I understand how to use them with JPanel (which applies to GLPanel) but is it possible to use it with GLCanvas? How would you do it if it is possible?

-Dan

Comment: What does GLCanvas extend?

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you elaborate how you thrown the GLPanel onto the GLCanvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(OK, I just now looked up the [GLCanvas API](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/javax/media/opengl/awt/GLCanvas.html))
Q: What does GLCanvas extend?
A: Canvas, an AWT component.

Q: Does AWT have key bindings?
A: No. So the overall answer is you can't use Key Bindings directly with GLCanvas.

Perhaps it can be used *indirectly* by attaching the bindings to another Swing component in the same GUI.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I just looked at GLCanvas and it escaped me to look at AWT. I think I might just have a GLPanel thrown onto the GLCanvas. So your indirect mention gave me that idea, thanks :)